# Request a javascript array, use within a query to filter results, and return new javascript array

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a javascript array called: 'objectID'. It's populated with several different id's.

```
Example: objectID = ['465723', '654221, '632876', '102435', '320111', ...]
 (includes just 3-6 character numbers, not sure if entered as string or int)
```

I need to use 'objectID' to query the database.

**JS**

```
 jQuery.ajax({        
      type: "POST",
      url: "filter.php",
      data: { objectsArray : objectID },
      success: function(result) {
        console.log("Object Names:" + result);     
      }
 });
```

**filter.php**

```
...

 $myArray = $_REQUEST['objectsArray'];

 $qstring = "SELECT Name FROM objectlist WHERE ObjectID IN ($myArray)";

 $result = mysql_query($qstring);
 $results = array();

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
 {
    $results[] = $row;
 }

...
```

I need the filter script to return a javascript array containing the objects names:

```
Example: objectNames = ['Chair', 'Console', 'Lamp', 'Ball', 'TV', ...]
```

I'm getting the following error when requesting the array:

```
 "mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in"
```

It seems there's a problem with the query itself.

Comment: Search for JSON to traffic data

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11674313/250259) for how to troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encode your $results array as json and print it:

```
$myArray = $_REQUEST['objectsArray'];

//you must escape the array elements to prevent SQL injection
$n = count($myArray);
for ($i = 0; $i < $n; ++$i)
{
    $myArray[$i] = mysql_real_escape_string($myArray[$i]);
}
//join them with comma separator
$myArray = implode(',', $myArray);

$qstring = "SELECT Name FROM objectlist WHERE ObjectID IN ($myArray)";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $results[] = $row["Name"];
}

$result = json_encode($results);
print $result;
```

In javascript you will get the array of names.
Notes:

1. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Quote elements of `$myArray` before using them in SQL request.
2. mysql_* functions are deprecated.

Comment: Thanks, but there seems to be an error with the query, maybe it's not reading the array correctly?

Comment: @Mazka var_dump($myArray); before the query and let me know, what it gives.

Comment: Object Names:array(10) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "221466"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "188779"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "132494"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "129147"
  [4]=>
  string(6) "171673"
  [5]=>
  string(6) "245860"
  [6]=>
  string(6) "220905"
  [7]=>
  string(6) "255121"
  [8]=>
  string(6) "115823"
  [9]=>
  string(6) "255660"
}

Comment: Just one more thing, how do I access, let's say the result[2] from the success function within the ajax function. Because, console.log("Object:" + result[2]); won't show 'Lamp'.